# Get real ip with Openlitespeed as webserver with a reverse proxy in front of our Openlitespeed webservers

Tags: nginx, haproxy, squid, litespeed, openlitespeed

My issue is that I can get the real IP address from the client when I am using the openlitespeed webserver with a reversed proxy in front of my openlitespeed serveres.

We have the `ssl termination on the openlitespeed web serveres` and NOT on the proxy server.

The proxy is only going to farward the request to the correct server nothing else. We have multiple serveres.

We are at this point only able to get the reversed proxy IP address and not the client ip address.

We have tried this with haProxy and are now trying it with nginx as reversed proxy.
I have read that it wont work with haProxy, but nginx is a bit more flexible it think.

I have set the server `Use Client IP in Header to Yes` on the openlitespeed servere:

**My first question is:**

Is this possible or dosent the openlitespeed server support this at all.

Ref: https://clients.javapipe.com/knowledgebase/135/Real-Visitor-IPs-With-Website-DDoS-Protection.html
This says its built in on litespeed.

**My second question is:**
Do you know if this have been done successfully with haProxy, Nginx or Squid proxy?

**My third question is:**
Do anyone have a config that works for either haProxy, Nginx or Squid proxy.
Prefered: Nginx or haProxy

A big thanks in advance for anyone who can answer these questions.

Comment: in that link , OLS and LS enterprise work same way , if your proxy gives x-forwarded-for header , OLS should take it ,  you can enable OLS's debug log to see what exactly was the header it received

Comment: i will check that.

Comment: I set the server configuration error.log to 
Log Level Debug
Debug Level High

And now iam getting alot of stuff in the error log. I cant find any information about x-forwarder-for header

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that is doesn't not work with ols. The litespeed team has confirmed it. Though they might add support for proxy protocol in the future. We are now syncing the ssl from the webserver to the proxy making it s secure all the way.

Comment: Did OLS support Proxy Protocol now, or still not yet?!